# "have been" as standalone phrase

Tags: grammar

I'd need your help to understand if the phrase **"Have been"** can live as standalone phrase without the "to" in front of it  (es: to have been)
It is part of a longer phrase that say : [**"being here and now" or just "have been"**] wich should in some way ask to the hypothetical listener / reader the following: is my "being here and now" as a person more important or is what I "have been" the past more important?

The whole thing is part of a lyric.

Comment: **1.** Lyrics do not necessarily follow standard grammar. **2.** Without the actual example and some context, it is impossible to answer the question.

Comment: @Greybeard thanks.   Here are the lines that precede the one I'm seek help for.
What gives meaning to our life?
The moments you had?
The time they lasted?

"being here and now or just "have been"

Comment: In my opinion, it has to be "to have been" - on its own, in that context, "have been" is incomprehensible - even allowing for poetic licence.

Comment: @Greybeard: Thanks. I think I'll go for "to have been". Singing the particle "to" very softly and almost as a ghost word, will make it less invasive for the already wrote melody if compared with "having been" as suggested in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Have been* does not work there. What may work is either ***having been*** or (as was suggested in the comments) ***to have been***.

Here is a relevant example, from *Corpus of Contemporary American English* [(COCA)](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/):

> *The former NFL QB, whose claim to fame is **having been on ABC's "The Bachelor,"** has become an NFL analyst.*